# How to store the setting value is in my android app?

Tags: android

I'm beginner level for android app development.

I will create the android app to user for database management.(Database are in server.)

The database have more than 1 database.

Each user maybe using the database is same or is not same with other user.

So the setting value(Database Name, IP, Port) can be edit is in this app by user.

How to storing the setting value is in this android app for each user?

Please suggest me on best way for this and example (Kotlin or Java) if possible.

Comment: Have you tried using SharedPreferences for this?

Comment: Is it delete when app has uninstall or delete cache data of app?

Comment: yes, it gets deleted on app uninstall and on cache clear.

Comment: @AeNetPhornphithak _Is it delete when app has uninstall or delete cache data of app?_ You can control this using this flag (android:allowBackup) in the manifest file

Answer (score 1):

For storing user data (setting values in your case), you can use any of the following :

- **Internal file storage**: Store app-private files on the device file system.
- **External file storage**: Store files on the shared external file system. This is usually for shared user files, such as photos.
- **Shared preferences**: Store private primitive data in key-value pairs.
- **Databases**: Store structured data in a private database.

Keep in mind, the `Internal file storage`, `shared preferences` and `databases` will be cleared when your app is uninstalled, depending upon [`android:allowBackup`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#allowbackup)

For more, refer [source](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage)

Comment: @AeNetPhornphithak you're welcome, pls upvote/accept the answer if it helped

Comment: @ShreyGarg internal file storage will also be deleted, if the app is uninstalled

Answer (score 0):

to save data use `SharedPreferences`

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("key_string","string_value");
 editor.putInt("key_int", int_value);
 ........
 editor.commit();
```

to get the same data :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String string = prefs.getString("key_string", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
int some_int = prefs.getInt("key_int", 0); //0 is the default value.
```